# Hadoop machine configuration

Tags: hadoop, configuration, architecture, hive

I want to analyze 7TB of data and store the output in a database, say HBase.
My monthly increment is 500GB, but to analyze 500GB data I don't need to go through 7TB of data again.

Currently I am thinking of using Hadoop with Hive for analyzing the data, and 
Hadoop with MapReducer and HBase to process and store the data.

At the moment I have 5 machines of following configuration:

Data Node Server Configuration: 2-2.5 Ghz  hexa core CPU, 48 GB RAM, 1 TB -7200 RPM (X 8)

Number of data nodes: 5

Name Node Server: Enterprise class server configuration (X 2) (1 additional for secondary

I want to know if the above process is sufficient given the requirements, and if anyone has any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

**Sizing**
There is a formula given by Hortonworks to calculate your sizing

((Initial Size + YOY Growth + Intermediate Data Size) * Repl Cpount * 1.2) /Comp Ratio

Assuming default vars

repl_count == 3 (default)
comp_ration  = 3-4 (default)
Intermediate data size = 30%-50% of raw data size .-
1,2 factor - temp space

So for your first year, you will need 16.9 TB. You have 8TB*5 == 40. So space is not the topic.

**Performance**
5 Datanodes. Reading 1 TB takes in average 2.5 hours (source Hadoop - The definitive guide) on a single drive. 600 GB with one drive would be 1.5 hours. Estimating that you have replicated so that you can use all 5 nodes in parallel, it means reading the whole data with 5 nodes can get up to 18 minutes.

You may have to add some more time time depending on what you do with your queries and how have configured your data processing.

**Memory consumution**

48 GB is not much. The default RAM for many data nodes is starting from 128 GB. If you use the cluster only for processing, it might work out. Depending also a bit, how you configure the cluster and which technologies you use for processing. If you have concurrent access, it is likely that you might run into heap errors.

**To sum it up:**

It depends much what you want to do with you cluster and how complex your queries are. Also keep in mind that concurrent access could create problems.

If 18 minutes processing time for 600 GB data (as a baseline - real values depend on much factors unknown answering that questions) is enough and you do not have concurrent access, go for it.

Comment: As i said earlier i dont need to perform 7tb data everytime, every month i have to analyze 600GB of data only.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend transforming the data on arrival. Hive can give tremendous speed boost by switching to a columnar compressed format, like [ORC](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ORC) or [Parquet](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Parquet). We're talking about potential x30-x40 times [improvements in queries performance](http://hortonworks.com/blog/orcfile-in-hdp-2-better-compression-better-performance/). With latest Hive you can leverage [streaming data ingest](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Streaming+Data+Ingest) on ORC files.

You can leave things as you planned (HBase + Hive) and just rely on brute force 5 x (6 Core, 48GB, 7200 RPM) but you don't have to. A bit of work can get you into interactive ad-hoc query time territory, which will open up data analysis.